# Abort trap: 6 error with strncat()

Tags: c, abort

I am trying to write code where I must implement versions of the library functions strncpy, strncat, and strncmp but it gives me Abort trap: 6 error while running. Any ideas are much appreciated:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<string.h>

int main() {

    char str1[400];

    printf ("Enter the first string: ");
    fgets (str1, 400, stdin);

    char str2[400];

    printf ("Enter the second string: ");
    fgets (str2, 400, stdin);

    int num;

    printf ("Enter the number: ");
    scanf ("%d", &num);

    char dest[num];

    strncpy(dest, str2, num);
    dest[num] = '\0';

    printf ("strncpy is %s \n", dest);

    int lengthStr1 = strlen (str1);

    char str1copy [lengthStr1];
    strncpy(str1copy, str1, lengthStr1);
    str1copy [lengthStr1] = '\0';

    printf ("str1copy is %s \n", str1copy);

    strncat(str1copy, dest, num);
    printf ("strncat is %s\n", str1copy);
}
```

I know that my strncpy section works.

Comment: Would you ask a mechanic to fix your car without bringing it to the garage? Where are the functions you so-called implemented?

Comment: `dest[num] = '\0';` occurs out of bounds. `str1copy [lengthStr1] = '\0';` ditto.

Comment: Maybe I do not quite know what they mean by implement then.. I thought we just had to use the functions. How would you "implement" a function? @StoryTeller

Comment: `return_type func_name(parameters) { statements_to_execute; }` is how one "implements" a function.

Comment: Note: Names defined in the standard library are reserved. You must not define them in your code, nor redeclare them with a different signature.

Answer (score 2):

An array of size `n` has indexes `0` to `n-1`.

When you declare your array like this:

```
char dest[num];
```

Then do this:

```
dest[num] = '\0';
```

You are accessing an offset one byte past the end of the array.  Doing so invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests in a crash.

Since you want to copy `num` bytes into this array, the size should be 1 more to make room for the null byte.

```
char dest[num+1];
```

Then setting `dest[num]` makes sense.

There's a similar error with `str1copy`.  In this case however using `lengthStr1-1` as the offset isn't enough.  You copy in `lengthStr` bytes from `str1` then an additional `num` bytes from `dest`.  So the length has to be the sum of those, plus 1 for the null terminating byte.

```
char str1copy [lengthStr1+dest+1];
strncpy(str1copy, str1, lengthStr1);
str1copy [lengthStr1] = '\0';

printf ("str1copy is %s \n", str1copy);

strncat(str1copy, dest, num);
str1copy [lengthStr1+dest] = '\0';
printf ("strncat is %s\n", str1copy);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the null be in dest[num] but we make the length of dest[] num+1? Because we have num amount of things to put in the dest char array.

Comment: @studentNeedHelp If you want `num` bytes copied, then yes it need to be 1 larger.  Also, you're not setting aside enough space for `str1copy`.  See my edit.